pgloader loading from CSV with blob data
I am trying to load a csv file utf-8 encoded into postgres using pgloader which contains blob data basically it is a AES key following is the load file
 LOAD CSV
     FROM 'report_info.csv'
     INTO postgresql://username:password@x.x.x.x:5432/db_name
          TARGET TABLE report_info
          ( 
            id,
            status,
            text1 bytea using ( byte-vector-to-bytea :text1),
            text2 bytea using ( byte-vector-to-bytea :text2),
            aes_key bytea using ( byte-vector-to-bytea :aes_key),
            name
          )
               
     WITH skip header = 1,
          fields optionally enclosed by '"',
          fields escaped by double-quote,
          fields terminated by ','

     SET client_encoding to 'utf-8',
          work_mem to '12MB',
          standard_conforming_strings to 'on'; 

I have tried providing transformation function in load file it resulted in exception
Error:
in: LAMBDA (PGLOADER.SOURCES::ROW)
(PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::BYTE-VECTOR-TO-BYTEA :TEXT1)
note: deleting unreachable code
(PGLOADER.TRANSFORMS::BYTE-VECTOR-TO-BYTEA :AES_KEY)

Probably in your database doesn't exist the extension pgcrypto to handle AES keys to bytea transformations. Check with select * from pg_extension; and if not exists create it with create extension pgcrypto;

Or maybe your aes_key field already is in bytea hex format, check your input data.
